web video server over HTTPS
I'm on ROS 2 Humble and my web app is on https. Is there any way I can make web_video_server stream the image topics over HTTPS/SSL instead of HTTP so I can use them inside my HTTPS web app?
This is how I use web_video_server inside my web app:
<mat-tab-group>
          <mat-tab label="RGB Camera">
            <img class="img-fluid" [style.width.px]="getWidthOfDiv()" [style.height.px]="getWidthOfDiv()/2"
            src="http://localhost:8080/stream?topic=/stereo/left/image_rect_color_out1_high"> 
            </mat-tab>
          <mat-tab label="Depth Camera">
             <img class="img-fluid" [style.width.px]="getWidthOfDiv()" [style.height.px]="getWidthOfDiv()/2"
            src="http://localhost:8080/stream?topic=/stereo/depth"> </mat-tab>
        </mat-tab-group>

I can't find any useful resources to help me make this happen, I've opened an issue, video server over HTTPS #141, on GitHub but the web_server_video repo seems to be dead.
Is this possible at all? Is there any alternative that streams image topics over HTTPS that you've worked with and recommend?

As far as I know the web_video_server doesn't support HTTPs. I looked into that about 6 years ago, too, and recall not finding anything. But it's also really not such a good option for video streaming, see this comparison I wrote: https://transitiverobotics.com/blog/streaming-video-from-robots
